# cleaning up some complicated logic for different conditions

Tags: java

```
Java 8
```

I have the following chart that will do something based on the conditions in the below table

[image]

Just wondering is this the best way to satisfy all conditions

```
private void setDisplayTheStars() {
    if (discount && rate) {
        2Stars = true;
    }
    else if (!discount && rate) {
        2Stars = true;
    }
    else if (discount && !rate) {
        1Stars = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are multiple ways this could be implemented. I'd put the number of stars into an integer and break it up between either discount/no-discount or rate/no-rate, and handle the other condition inside a wider conditional. FWIW, this is about as simple as business logic will ever be, so it really doesn't matter that much until it gets a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set `2Stars` if `rate` is true;

Then check if `discount` is true - then set `1Stars` to true.

```
if (rate) {
    2Stars = true;
}
else if (discount) {
    1Stars = true;
}
```

If you are declaring boolean, then it can be done as

```
boolean twoStars = rate == true;
boolean oneStars = !twoStars && discount == true;
```

Comment: From you logic we only set to 2Stars if the rate is true. I was thinking that 2Stars should be set given that if `discount is false` and `rate is true`.

Comment: That is *one* of the conditions. 2Stars is true when both rate and discount are true. This means 2Stars must be true when rate alone is true.

Comment: To understand this, just have a look at your table and answer the question: when should 2Stars be true